# CLOZE TEST: Need help with words' meanings!

Tags: word-difference

> Extreme water events like this are dramatic reminders of the power of
>   the wind. It's one part of the weather we generally don't give a
>   second thought to in Britain but it plays a vital role in people's
>   lives across the world. Without the formation and circulation of winds
>   there would quite ___ be no climate.
>
> A. easily B. rightly  C. surely D. simply

According to the answer, the answer is D; but can't I choose C, for instance?

Comment: Erm... I thought we ***Brits*** were supposed to be legendary when it comes to thinking and talking about the weather. But obviously we don't concern ourselves so much with monsoons and typhoons, because they only normally happen closer to the equator.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Uhm, yes, indeed you are correct. There’s another passage in the same test paper that reads: “[...] The weather is a national obsession in Britain, perhaps because it is do changeable.” Just focus on the cloze for now.

Comment: I voted to close the question (I think it's a stupid "test", with nothing absolute about which word is "correct").

Comment: word meanings or the meaning of words or the meanings of words, quite simply

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be also A. *quite easily,* where "easily" means "probably; almost certainly" ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/easily))

"Quite surely" would mean "reliably," but this sounds like a prediction based on experience, so it does not work there.